# Awk to find duplicates across column

Tags: awk, solaris

I have a bunch of dns entries in a file

```
a1.us.company.com ------ DO NOT PRINT
a2.us.us.company.com ------PRINT------ ("us" is repeated)
a3.eu.a3.compamy.com ------PRINT------ ("a3" is repeated)
a4.tx.a4.tx.company.com -----PRINT------- ("a4" and "tx" is repeated)

awk 'BEGIN {FS="."; OFS="."} {if ($2==$3) print $1"."$2"."$NF}' device_list
awk 'BEGIN {FS="."; OFS="."} {if ($1==$3) print $1"."$2"."$NF}' device_list
```

I am using 2 commands above.

Can someone please give me a awk command that lists duplicate columns per row.
Some of the names are crazy with as many as 7 to 8 . separated fields.

Comment: Does it have to be awk command?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat file
a1.us.company.com
a2.us.us.company.com
a3.eu.a3.compamy.com
a4.tx.a4.tx.company.com

$ awk -F'.' '{delete seen; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (seen[$i]++) {print; next} }' file
a2.us.us.company.com
a3.eu.a3.compamy.com
a4.tx.a4.tx.company.com
```

Note that using `delete seen` is GNU-awk specific, with other awks you can delete the whole array by doing `split("",seen)`.

Comment: I can't give you more +1 but that trick of using `split` to delete an array is simply brilliant.

Comment: Wish I could claim it, but before gawk `split("",array)` was the way to delete an array for 30+ years....

Answer (score 1):

```
 $ awk -F. '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(x[$i]++){print;delete x;next}}' file
 a2.us.us.company.com 
 a3.eu.a3.compamy.com 
 a4.tx.a4.tx.company.com
```

If you want to try this on a `Solaris/SunOS system`, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` , `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`

Comment: Works for small files but for large files with more than 100K records prints everything.

Comment: Are you sure ? I don't think so

Comment: You could simplify it some by changing `(0<x[$i]++)` to `(x[$i]++)`

Comment: looks to be issue with my file.

Comment: Since you only delete the array when x[$i]++ is true, if that condition is not true on a given line then x[] will still be present/populated on the next line so then the script will be wrongly comparing fields across lines not just within a line. Also, you mention several awks but IIRC none of them supports `delete array`, only `delete array[index]`.

Comment: +1 Ed Morton : Thanks for sharing knowledge, I really have no idea about IIRC, but it supports gawk and several awks which I used...so far... I referred this http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Delete.html -- Thanks  -- Akshay..

Comment: `IIRC` means `If I Remember Correctly`. The reference you gave is for GNU awk which is the awk that does support deleting a whole array.